# How do pass an i18n interpolation variable inside the form label helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

Suppose one has the following en.yml

```
#en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    books:
       price: "Price in %{currency}"
```

Then one can do the following in a view

```
<%= t :price, :scope => "activerecord.attributes.book", :currency => "USD"%>
```

and it will print "Price in USD".

But I can't figure out how to pass the currency when this translation is in a form

```
# views/books/edit.html
f.label :price
```

understandably throws an I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument, but I can't figure out what the syntax might be to pass the missing argument

```
# views/books/edit.html
f.label :price, :currency => "USD"
```

does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would try:

```
<%= f.label I18n.t(:price, :scope => "activerecord.attribute.book", :currency => "USD") %>
```

Comment: That doesn't really work. If the translation for price is "Price in USD" then your label tag will look like <label for="book_Price in USD">Price in USD</label>, which is not valid HTML.

Comment: i see, then this: <%= f.label :price, I18n.t(:price, :scope => "activerecord.books.price", :currency => "USD") %> should be better.  Sorry i can't run and test it right now.. @work with no rails availble ;-(

Comment: Right, that's what I started with (see original question).  However, after much investigation, I think that the exception I'm seeing is actually being through by the client_side_validations module.  I would guess that your second suggestion in your comment here would work fine if the client_side_validations module was not involved.